# Is it "a professor at the institute" or "... in the institute"?

Tags: prepositions

I am not a native English speaker.

Examples
"Peter Parker is a professor **at** the Institute of Sociology **at** the University of Vulcan"

"Peter Parker is a professor **in** the Institute of Sociology **in** the University of Vulcan"

Answer (score 1):

> Peter Parker is a professor **at** the Institute of Sociology **at** the University of Vulcan.

I did a [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) search to help me answer your question. I compared the strings "professor in" and "professor at." What I'm looking for is not really grammatical correctness - either usage would make sense - but rather conventionality. What do writers tend to do? What do readers expect? What is more established usage?

In my Compare search between "professor at" and "professor in," "Professor at" was typically followed by the names of institutes or schools. Most of the top results are schools like Georgetown, Columbia, Princeton, and University of ______. (The sum is about 5000 results for *at* compared to about 100 for *in*.) This confirms my general understanding: usually professors work *at* a specific institution, a sense that works well with a sense of a specific place, as [Wiktionary entry 1 for *at*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at#English) illustrates.

Meanwhile, "professor in" is often followed by indications of department. "Professor in the department of ______" is pretty common, as is "professor in the division of ______." Again, this confirms my understanding: one is in an area (a field or specialty) but at a specific place (an institution).

So this clarifies the last part: Peter Parker is a professor *at* a university.

As for the first part, it made me wonder whether an *institute* is more like a department or a university. The answer? Most often someone is a professor *at* the institute (177 results to *in*'s 11.) So common usage suggests that most times *at* would be applied to an institute name as well. Examples in the wild, [like this page for visiting scholars at Brown](https://watson.brown.edu/gpd/people/visiting-scholars/), tend to support this convention. Nasser Yassin is an example of the double usage:

> Dr Nasser Yassin is the Director of Research at the Issam Fares Institute for Public Policy and International Affairs at the American University of Beirut (AUB), Lebanon ...

Answer (score 0):

you asked a good question. actually, there is a little nuance between **at** and **in** in these situations. here, **at** just refers to the place. but **in** implies the current situations.
in other words, when you say:"my sister is at the school" you actually mean that your sister locates in that place. in other hand, when you say: "my sister is in the school" you mean that your sister is an student.
hope it helps you.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The situation is rather that *My sister is in the school* means that she is inside the school building and *my sister is at the school* means that she is on the grounds of the school. These are to be distinguished from being *in school* and *at school*, where *school* does not refer to a specific institution or location but to a state or habitual activity (e.g. *at home*, *in jail*, *at church*, *in rehearsal* — working professors are not usually *in school*, but they are *at work*). In any case, the question is about identifying an affiliation, not an occupation.

Answer (score -2):

**At**. When referring to places, use *at*. It is used for more accurately referred places. For example:

*On our trip, we'll be staying **in** a hotel.*
Not specific one. Just stating you'll be staying in a hotel rather than a farm, for instance.

*On our trip, we'll be staying **at** Royal Inn Hotel.*
Specific one. We're talking about the Royal Inn Hotel, not just any hotel.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I'm afraid your understanding of the distinction is not correct, however. Specificity does not govern the use of *in* or *at*. If anything, it is *more* common in American English, for instance, to say *On our trip, we'll be staying at a hotel*; you would use *in* if describing the room or building within that hotel, e.g. *we'll be staying in the east building*, *we'll be staying in the honeymoon suite*, *we'll be staying in an oceanside room*.